# Searching an instance in dataframe in Pyspark with filter takes too much time

Tags: search, dataframe, filter, pyspark, instance

I have a DataFrame with N Attributes (Atr1, Atr2, Atr3, ..., AtrN) and an individual instance with the same [1..N-1] attributes, except the Nth one.

I want to check if there is any instance in the DataFrame with the same values for the Attributes [1..N-1] of the instance, and if it exists an occurrence of that instance, my goal is to get the instance in the DataFrame with the Attributes [1..N].

For example, if I have:

```
Instance:

[Row(Atr1=u'A', Atr2=u'B', Atr3=24)]

Dataframe:

+------+------+------+------+
| Atr1 | Atr2 | Atr3 | Atr4 |
+------+------+------+------+
|  'C' |  'B' |  21  |  'H' |
+------+------+------+------+
|  'D' |  'B' |  21  |  'J' |
+------+------+------+------+
|  'E' |  'B' |  21  |  'K' |
+------+------+------+------+
|  'A' |  'B' |  24  |  'I' |
+------+------+------+------+
```

I want to get the 4th row of the DataFrame also with the value of Atr4.

I tried it with "filter()" method like this:

```
df.filter("Atr1 = 'C' and Atr2 = 'B', and Atr3 = 24").take(1)
```

And I get the result I wanted, but it took much time.

So, my question is: is there any way to do the same but in less time?

Thanks!

Comment: A little more information would be helpful here.  In particular: how much time is it taking?  How long would you like it to take?  How big is the cluster/hardware you're running this on?  In general, no matter how big your cluster is, there will be some overhead when doing any spark operation because spark has to distribute your data and code to the cluster and then gather the results.  Doing something simple like this in pyspark will never be as quick as doing something similarly simple in python on your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use locality sensitive hashing(minhashLSH) to find the closest neighbor and check whether it's same or not.

Since, your data has strings , you need to process it before applying LSH.
We will be using pyspark ml's feature module

**Start with stringIndexing and onehotencoding**

```
df= spark.createDataFrame([('C','B',21,'H'),('D','B',21,'J'),('E','c',21,'K'),('A','B',24,'J')], ["attr1","attr2","attr3","attr4"])


for col_ in ["attr1","attr2","attr4"]:

    stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol=col_, outputCol=col_+"_")
    model = stringIndexer.fit(df)
    df = model.transform(df)
    encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCol=col_+"_", outputCol="features_"+col_, dropLast = False)
    df = encoder.transform(df)


df = df.drop("attr1","attr2","attr4","attr1_","attr2_","attr4_")
df.show()


+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|attr3|features_attr1|features_attr2|features_attr4|
+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|   21| (4,[2],[1.0])| (2,[0],[1.0])| (3,[1],[1.0])|
|   21| (4,[0],[1.0])| (2,[0],[1.0])| (3,[0],[1.0])|
|   21| (4,[3],[1.0])| (2,[1],[1.0])| (3,[2],[1.0])|
|   24| (4,[1],[1.0])| (2,[0],[1.0])| (3,[0],[1.0])|
+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

**Add id and assemble all features vectors**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id

df = df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
df.show()


assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = ["features_attr1", "features_attr2", "features_attr4", "attr3"]
                            , outputCol = "features")
df_ = assembler.transform(df)
df_ = df_.select("id", "features")
df_.show()


+----------+--------------------+
|        id|            features|
+----------+--------------------+
|         0|(10,[2,4,7,9],[1....|
|         1|(10,[0,4,6,9],[1....|
|8589934592|(10,[3,5,8,9],[1....|
|8589934593|(10,[1,4,6,9],[1....|
+----------+--------------------+
```

**Create your minHashLSH model and search for nearest neighbors**

```
mh = MinHashLSH(inputCol="features", outputCol="hashes", seed=12345)
model = mh.fit(df_)
model.transform(df_)
key = df_.select("features").collect()[0]["features"]
model.approxNearestNeighbors(df_, key, 1).collect()
```

output

```
[Row(id=0, features=SparseVector(10, {2: 1.0, 4: 1.0, 7: 1.0, 9: 21.0}), hashes=[DenseVector([-1272095496.0])], distCol=0.0)]
```